# Disable Snackbar animation [Material-ui]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to disable the transition for the `Snackbar`?

`TransitionProps` (https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-props) seems to indicate that if I set a prop of `enter` to false it won't animate in, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
<Snackbar
  TransitionProps={{
    enter: false,
  }}
/>
```

**Use case:** I am rendering a `Snackbar` via SSR. I want to show a notification that javascript is disabled so in this case I'm rendering `Snackbar` via SSR with javascript disabled. The DOM is added, but the Snackbar never animates in because the javascript is disabled.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will work, fully disabling the animation, even in SSR with javascript disabled:

```
<Snackbar
  open
  TransitionProps={{
    appear: false,
  }}
/>
```

If you can't get that to work the following will definitely force it to work:

```
<Snackbar
  ContentProps={{
    style: {
      opacity: 1,
      transform: 'none',
    },
  }}
  TransitionProps={{
    appear: false,
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation of material/ui just showed me that if you want to do that with passing attribute to the react class you can do it by setting `transitionDuration` to `0`.

So your code would be like this:

```
<Snackbar
  transitionDuration={0}
/>
```

Let me know if that did work for you.

Comment: That does indeed turn off the animation, visually, but the animation is still happening programatically (at 0ms) which is a problem for my use-case.

Comment: `TransitionProps={{appear: false}}` disables the animation in a better way, but unfortunately JS is still required so it doesn't work with SSR.

Comment: You're right. Your `appear` offer is better than, I didn't find that option myself